# Utilizing Static Access Modifier in Classes

Tags: java, class

I am trying to design a two player dice game like yahtzee. In the main class I instantiate two players and two scorecards, one for each player. I then loop through each player's turn. Each player rolls five dice up to three times in order to make certain combinations. Whithin the method playerTurn(), in the last two lines where I try to access the class scorecard it is not accessing the correct scorecard. 
For example: if player one completes their turn and rolls 4 ones and chooses to take the one category in the method getCategory(), the method will set ones = to 4. Then when printScorecard() is called, the scorecard will print with every category set to 0 but ones, which will be set to 4. After player two finishes their turn and rolls 3 twos (which is equal to 6 points), and chooses to take the two category in the method getCategory(), the method will set twos = to 6. However, when I then try to print player two's scorecard in the method printScorecard(), it will print ones=4, twos=6, threes=0, fours=0, fives=0, sixes=0. Since it is player two's scorecard and player one is the one who rolled 4 ones, it should print ones=0. It will continue adding each players scores to the same scorecard like this. Why is this happening when I have instantiated two different scorecards?

Here is the Main Class:

```
 public class Main {
    Random rand = new Random();
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            System.out.println("What is player one's name?"); 
        String name1 = sc.next();
        System.out.println("What is player two's name?"); 
        String name2 = sc.next();
        Player p1=new Player(name1);
        Scorecard s1=new Scorecard();
        Player p2=new Player(name2);
        Scorecard s2=new Scorecard ();
        for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
          {
            System.out.println(name1+"'s turn:");
            playerTurn(p1, s1);
            System.out.println(name2+"'s turn:");
            playerTurn(p2, s2);
          }
        System.out.println("Game Over. Player one's score is " + s1.getScore()); 

        System.out.println("Game Over. Player two's score is " + s2.getScore()); 
        if (s1.getScore()>s2.getScore())
            System.out.println("Player one wins!!!");
        if (s2.getScore()>s1.getScore())
            System.out.println("Player two wins!!!");
        else
            System.out.println("It's a tie.");

    }

    public static void playerTurn(Player player, Scorecard scorecard)
    {
        {


            player.getCup().printDice();
            for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Do you want to roll again (y/n)?");
                String answer =sc.next();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How many dice do you want to reroll?");
                    int roll=sc.nextInt();
                    for (int j=0; j<roll; j++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter the number of a die (1-5) you want to reroll");
                        int num=sc.nextInt();
                        player.getCup().reroll(num);;
                    }
                    player.getCup().printDice();
                }
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                    break;
            }
            scorecard.getCategory();    //Here when I access scorecard it is not working
            scorecard.printScoreCard();

        }
    }
```

Here is the class Scorecard:

```
     public class Scorecard 


    {
        static Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    private static int ones;
    private static int twos;
    private static int threes;
    private static int fours;
    private static int fives;
    private static int sixes;


    public Scorecard()
    {
        ones=00;
        twos=00;
        threes=00;
        fours=00;
        fives=00;
        sixes=00;


    }

    public static void printScoreCard()
    {
        //System.out.println(Player.getName() +"'s Score Card:");
        System.out.println(" *******Score Card*******");
        System.out.println("Ones...................." +ones);
        System.out.println("Twos...................."+twos);
        System.out.println("Threes.................."+threes);
        System.out.println("Fours..................."+fours);
        System.out.println("Fives..................."+fives);
        System.out.println("Sixes..................."+sixes);
        System.out.println("************************");
    }

    public static void getCategory()
    {
        int selection=0;
        int score=0;
        System.out.println("Which category do you want to take (enter a number 1-6):"); 
        if (ones==00)
            System.out.println("1. Ones");
        if (twos==00)
            System.out.println("2. Twos");
        if (threes==00)
            System.out.println("3. Threes");
        if (fours==00)
            System.out.println("4. Fours");
        if (fives==00)
            System.out.println("5. Fives");
        if (sixes==00)
            System.out.println("6. Sixes");
        selection=sc.nextInt();

        if (selection==1)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(1);
            ones=score;
        }

        else    if (selection==2)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(2);
            twos=score;
        }
        else    if (selection==3)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(3);
            threes=score;
        }
        else    if (selection==4)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(4);
            fours=score;
        }
        else    if (selection==5)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(5);
            fives=score;
        }
        else    if (selection==6)
        {
            score= addCertainDice(6);
            sixes=score;
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you find out what `static` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a field as `static`, that means there is one copy of the field, not one per instance.

That means the `getCategory` and `printScoreCard` methods of `Scorecard` (and any other methods you add later) access the same fields no matter which scorecard you call them on.

The solution is to make those fields not `static`.

You haven't posted your `Player` class, but you should check whether it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the whole question but you made a basic mistake: the state in the Scorecard class is in static variables. Those are shared among all instances of the class. So remove the `static` keywords there and from the methods that want to access them.

Note: One way new programmers get into this situation is by declaring their methods `static`, then the compiler or Eclipse complains that static methods can't access the instance variables, then Eclipse offers to fix that by making the variables `static`. It's the wrong suggestion although it makes the code compile.